Using $(OutDir) in a property group of a property sheet
Using Visual Studio 2022 with a C++ solution.
The below property sheet is working fine:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DestinationFolders>$(OutDir)</DestinationFolders>
    </CopyFileToFolders>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

But the below one is not working (when output directory is changed in project properties):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomDestination>$(OutDir)</CustomDestination>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DestinationFolders>$(CustomDestination)</DestinationFolders>
    </CopyFileToFolders>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

This makes sense as "CustomDestination" property is evaluated before "OutDir" is well-defined from VS IDE, on the contrary to the "CopyFileToFolder"->"DestinationFolders" item metadata which is evaluated after all properties.
Is there an elegant way to predefine "CustomDestination" with any value including some $(X) before the "CopyFileToFolders" item, so I can move both on separate property sheets ?
_
Additional note:

I came out with the below workaround consisting in managing $(OutDir) separately like this:

<PropertyGroup>
  <CustomDestination>$(ProjectDir);$(SolutionDir)SomeDirectory</CustomDestination>
  <UseOutDir>Yes</UseOutDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
    <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
    <FileType>Document</FileType>
    <DestinationFolders Condition="'$(UseOutDir)' == ''">$(CustomDestination) </DestinationFolders>
    <DestinationFolders Condition="'$(UseOutDir)' != ''">$(OutDir);$(CustomDestination) </DestinationFolders>
  </CopyFileToFolders>
</ItemGroup>

But I was wondering if someone would come out with a more generic solution.

I also tried something like this:

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomDestination>%24(OutDir);%24(ProjectDir)</CustomDestination>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DestinationFolders>$(CustomDestination)</DestinationFolders>
    </CopyFileToFolders>
  </ItemGroup>

But I don't know how to make VS/MSBuild to replace $(X) contents into $(CustomDestination) property value.

In MSBuild, properties are evaluated before items - see Evaluation phase. I would not expect the result you are seeing -- unless the C++ project is doing something other than just Importing the property sheet files. You could put CustomDestination in a Directory.Build.targets.

Hi @Charly, what does it print after you input  '%(CopyFileToFolders.DestinationFolders)?

Hi @JonathanDodds, here CustomDestination is defined from $(OutDir) but $(OutDir) can be modified from IDE (project properties), and in this case, the definition appears in .vcxproj file after property sheets imports. Then CustomDestination is defined with the default value of $(OutDir), not the final one. And all this happens before any item is evaluated.

@Charly So you are saying that CustomDestination is defined from OutDir and then OutDir is redefined in the Imported property sheet. But you want CustomDestination to have the property sheet value of OutDir? If yes, then move the CustomDestination definition to be after the property sheet import (or in the property sheet file after the OutDir redefinition.)

@JonathanDodds: No,I did say "$(OutDir) can be modified from IDE (project properties), and in this case, the definition appears in .vcxproj file after property sheets imports". When using IDE/HMI we cannot control the placement order of property sheets imports regard to $(OutDir) final definition in the .vcxproj file and I still need to be compliant with IDE/HMI behavior for team working and maintenance purposes. I found the solution anyway (see below). Regards.

The C++ team really made a mess with their MSBuild project implementation.

I found a solution !
Defining "CustomDestination" as a custom item value instead of a property makes it evaluated after properties, then with the latest $(OutDir) value.
  <!--Define CustomDestination-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomDestination Include="$(OutDir)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--Print CustomDestination value in build output-->
  <Target Name="PrintDestTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="PrintDestTarget: CustomDestination = '@(CustomDestination)'" />
  </Target>

  <!--Use CustomDestination value to copy file-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <CopyFileToFolders Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)somefile.bin">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DestinationFolders>@(CustomDestination)</DestinationFolders>
    </CopyFileToFolders>
  </ItemGroup>

Note that the setup logic of items is different than properties:
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomDestination Include="Smith" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomDestination Include="Adams" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="PrintDestTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="PrintDestTarget: CustomDestination = '@(CustomDestination)'" />
</Target>

Will output "Smith;Adams".
I am not shure if it is possible to modify an item value, but one can still define new ones as needed.

From looking at your property sheet, it seems you want to copy somefile.bin to your custom path. I copied your  property sheet (You said the one is not working) to my local c++ project for test and it worked fine. It can recognize $(CustomDestination) defined in PropertyGroup.
Here is my test result:
ENV: Visual Studio 2022(17.10.4)


But the below one is not working

Do you mean the task CopyFileToFolders is unable to copy somefile.bin file to your custom destination or it can not evaluate $(CustomDestination)? And could you see warning/error messages during the build process?
If you want to make sure whether "CustomDestination" property is evaluated before "CopyFileToFolders" item, you can directly print their values.
<Target Name="test">
  <Message Text="'%(CopyFileToFolders.FileType)'" />
  <Message Text="'%(CopyFileToFolders.DestinationFolders)'" />
</Target>



Hi again @Dou Xu-MSFT ! Sorry for reply delay and thank you again for helping us :) I forgot to mention that to reproduce the issue one must change the default value for output directory using IDE Project properties window. The problem is that CustomDestination is defined with the default value of $(OutDir), and not the final one defined using IDE. Which makes sense as properties are evaluated in order and property sheets are imported by IDE in .vcxproj file before $(OutDir) final definition. But how to deal with it elegantly ? Maybe if we define CustomDestination as an item metadata ?
